How do I portray a character (child) that has had their consciousness spontaneously transferred to a different person (adult)?
In a screenplay I'm writing, one of the characters, a four-year-old girl, has her consciousness transferred into the body of a 25-year-old woman. How do I go about doing that? What is the mental/physical impact of such a transformation? How would others around her act?

We cannot and will not write your story for you. You can ask how we would approach that problem, but not for us to provide a solution to you. Here is how I would find those answers:
Either do research, or make it up
How do I go about doing that?
You need to come up with a technique that fits your narrative. Are you writing hard science fiction? Then you need to do some research into the current status of science regarding reading brain content and future projections about the possibility of mind transference. Are you writing an action thriller? Then construct a device that looks like it could transfer minds. You can look at how other movies do this. Commonly, two dentist chairs are used and some kind of hairdryer helmet and EEG electrodes.
What is the mental/physical impact of such a transformation?
That is the core of your narrative, isn't it? Depending on what the impact is, your story will develop into completely different directions. So there are two things you can do: Either deduce the impact from the story you want to tell. Then the impact will be whatever progresses the story in the direction you want. Or do research, again, into what scholars suppose would happen when consciousness is transfered, and shape your story accordingly.
How would others around her act?
From your personal experience with other people, your insight into yourself, and your knowledge of psychology, deduce plausible reactions in people with different personalities. Or, from your viewing experience of different movies, how are people shown to react to similar events?

There are a few movies in which a child's mind is transfered into an adult body, among them the movies Big and Jumanji. You could would view (some of) them for inspiration and to see how this is handled.
